# How to read dom element value by jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to read every element in the same name. I tried to iterate using each as under

```
var subarray=[];
$('.subjects').each(function() {
  subarray[counter] = $('.subjects').val();
  counter = counter + 1;                
});
```

But how can we refer or point to the value in the specific (one by one ) element in it. ? To clarify, there are 5 inputs having same name . And i want to read values of each of those elements.

Comment: use $(this).val();

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, you could have answered it with your comment. IT worked right . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` keyword to reference to the each element in the collection.

Or you can just use `Array#push` to store each element inside newly created `arr`.

```js
var arr = [];
$('.subjects').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());      
  arr.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='subjects' type='text' value='1'>
<input class='subjects' type='text' value='2'>
<input class='subjects' type='text' value='3'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.subjects').each(function(_element){
    subarray[counter]=$(this).val();
counter=counter+1;              
});
```

You would want to use either the $(this) handled that jQuery provides, or add a variable in the function as shown with the **_elment** variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this one

```
var subarray= [];
$("input[name='subjects[]']").each(function() {
subarray.push($(this).val());
});
```